# Check for Key press event in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<System.Windows.Forms.Keys>`.
I want to check if all Keys in the list are pressed in a keydown event.

But how?

My method is:

```
public bool Triggered( string indentifier, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    List<Keys> keys = Shortcuts.Keys.First( x => Shortcuts[x].Indentifier == indentifier );
    keys.Reverse();
    foreach( Keys key in keys )
    {
        if ( e.KeyCode != key )
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Getting the keys works but the check don't.

Comment: what issue are you facing in above code?

Comment: e.KeyCode is the same Key every time. But when I do if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S ) in the real KeyDownEvent it works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: what type of keys are present in the list? are there and command keys like Ctril,Shift,Alt etc?

Comment: Jeroen Heier I'm not very good at english and not able to write productive questions

Comment: In the Keys list are as example Keys.ControlKey and Keys.S

Comment: Are they stored like keys[0] & keys[1] ?

Comment: Yes, I reversed the list because KeyCode is Key.ControlKey and keys[0] was Keys.S before reversing

Comment: are there always going to be 2 values in the list?

Comment: Sometimes three but minimum 2

Comment: at 0 is always going to be the command key right ?

Comment: The order I add the key list is first Keys.ControlKey and then Keys.S

Comment: How can e.KeyCode be 2 Keys at the same time? if( e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey && e.KeyCode == Keys.S ) would return true

Comment: you will need to provide what shortcut's structure is

Comment: Shortcuts is Dictionary<List<Keys>,ShortcutInfo> and ShortcutInfo is a class with two properties called Indentifier and Desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer to your question `Why is e.KeyCode the same key every time but when I do if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S )` because it is a `flag enum` [(answer for detailed explanation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c).

you can do is change your code to :

```
 List<Keys> keys = Shortcuts.Keys.First( x => Shortcuts[x].Indentifier == indentifier );
 keys.Reverse();

 Keys allKey = Keys.None;
 keys.ForEach(ele => allKey |= ele);

 return (e.KeyData == allKey);
```

Comment: I have another question... Why is e.KeyCode the same key every time but when I do if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S ) in the real KeyDownEvent it would return true?

Comment: @SmoothOS if this answer helped please mark it correct

Comment: When I press a key the program hang up for about 3 seconds. I think there is a problem with your code snippet

Comment: @SmoothOS I have tried that code and does not go in hang state,debug and see where is it hanging?

Comment: It hangs at the line where I check for 3 keys

Comment: which are those three keys ?

Comment: Keys.Control Keys.Shift Keys.S

Comment: I think I got the problem